# Why the following code prints an empty list (while the second is an index error)?

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
my_list = [1]
# When using a range as index
print(my_list[1:])  # Gives an empty list

# When using a single number as index
print(my_list[1])  # Gives an error
```

Both print statement contains list with invalid index since my_list is only of length 1 (Therefore only has index 0 or -1). Why first print could produce an empty list while the second print gives an error. Is there any underlying principle or mechanism causing this? Thanks for enlightening

Comment: You are printing a string, not a list...

Comment: print(my_list[0]). Also, your list only has 1 element so mylist[1] will trigger the error List index out of range.

Comment: But when I run print(my_list[1:]), the output is an empty list. I would expect an error here

Comment: I know why the second print statement is an error. I just couldn't get why the first print would output a result of empty list without problem

Comment: @Black Python allows an empty list range, in which case you get an empty list.  In that case, since the empty range does not reference any list elements, its bounds do not have to lie within the list.  In general, if a part of a range lies outside of a list, that part is simply discarded when used as a slice.

Comment: `slicing` can give the empty_list.. while `Index` you try to access that index in the list if it is not present it will give an error..

Answer (score 0):

Lists are zero-indexed in python, which means the first item has an index of 0, the second item has an index of 1, and so on.

In your case above, my_list = [1], the list has only one item with the index 0.

```
my_list[1:]
```

When you use a **range** as an index (like my_list[1:]), it starts from index 1 and goes until the end of the list.
Because there is only one item in the list with an index of 0, there are no more items in the range [1:], and it results in an empty list.

```
my_list[1]
```

And, When you use a **single number** as an index (like my_list[1]),
you are trying to access the second item of the list, which doesn't exist in your case. Because there's only one item in the list with an index of 0, accessing an item with an index of 1 will result in an "IndexError" since it is out of range.

I hope it clarifies your question.